# How to disable the input field while clicking on checkbox using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have input text-field and Checkbox, when we click on Checkbox the text-field should get disabled. But I couldn't do that, couldn't able to figure out where i'm going wrong.

I have tried in this way:

```
<FormControlLabel
                                        control={
                                            <Checkbox
                                                // checked={this.state.games=== -1 ? true : false}
                                                onChange={this.handleTextField}
                                                name="games" color="primary"
                                            />}
                                        label="all"
                                    />
                                }

 <TextField required type="number" name='games' variant="outlined"
                                        disabled={this.state.games === -1 ? true : false}
                                        placeholder="value"
                                        onChange={this.handleTextField}
                                    />
```

OnChange method:

```
handleTextField = (e) => {

 this.setState({games: e.target.checked === true ? -1 : 0 || e.target.value})
}
```

Still textfield is not getting disabled.
Can anyone help me with this query?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.state = {
  games: 0,
}

handleTextField = (e) => {
  this.setState({ textValue: e.target.value })
}

toggleCheckbox = () => this.setState({ games: this.state.games === 0 ? -1 : 0 });

<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Checkbox
      checked={this.state.games === -1}
      onChange={this.toggleCheckbox}
      name="games"
      color="primary"
    />}
  label="all"
/>

<TextField required type="number" name='games' variant="outlined"
  disabled={this.state.games === -1}
  placeholder="value"
  onChange={this.handleTextField}
/>
```

I propose different idea, if you don't mind. Use one flag,`isCheckboxChecked`. Apply it on input checkbox and textfield.

Update:

I update the answer to rely based on `games` value

Comment: Hi, When we click on checkbox i have to get variable `games` value as -1. That is why i have given onChange method for both checkbox and textfield

Comment: When click on checkbox (it could be check or uncheck) or when the chechbox is checked the ```games``` state should be -1?

Comment: When we click on checkbox, it should be checked and value should be -1 and textfield will get disable

Comment: The thing is we'll be using one variable for both checkbox and text-field

Comment: @Sanjana if it is answer your question, please accept it as accepted answer

Comment: @Sanjana it would be good if you accept this answer if this answer solve your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.setState` to update the state value here:

```
handleTextField = (e) => {
 this.setState({
   games: e.target.checked === true ? -1 : 0 || e.target.value
});}
```

Comment: Yes, i've done that but still textfield is not getting disabled

Comment: @Sanjana: Can you try `console.log(event.target.)` too see target context?

Comment: data-indeterminate="false" getting the input tag in console

Comment: Is it input type checkbox?

Comment: The same way i declared above in my query.

Comment: @Sanjana: Can you reproduce the issue on boilerplate like jsfiddle? Your render function may not be triggered on state change.